# Uploading mysql database to web server i.e. remote server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How can i upload and run local mysql database to remote server?

Can i do it with phpmyadmin? Will it be secure?

Is there any other secure and good way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usaly you would use a (S)FTP example on windows you could use winSCP, Regarding to learn more have a read of this http://winscp.net/eng/docs/free_sftp_client_for_windows

Comment: Can you axplain how. i put all my phpmyadmin files to server using ftp. and can access phpmyadmin on remote server. its asking username and password which i never put. n dont kwow